# Who are the current day descendants of Ketura?

Tags: biblical-history

People have suggested to me that Abraham's descendants through "Keturah" may be linked to the Asian people. I'm curious if there's any evidence backing up this claim. Has anyone come across any Mefarshim  that discuss this topic?

Comment: The Rambam says that Keturah got mixed up in Yishmael. So even though Avraham sent benei keturah "to the east", which people say means Asia, but apparently it's not so simple.

Comment: The modern day "east" and the "east" of those days do not need to be identical. All we can tell is they ended up east of Israel. We also don't know how long they stayed there or if they kept moving. Perhaps at some point they turned.